# How can I have two columns with a combined width of 100% ?

Tags: html, css

They say, that a single picture can explain more than a tousand words, so here's my "more": http://www.imagebanana.com/view/hcqsz5fs/cols.png

My goal is to have the columns as shown on the image, with them together having 100% body width.

And my fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/c2JH3/ (note that this is just a mockup of my current work).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try to use imgur for hosting images.

Comment: If it helps: http://i.imgur.com/OoHNn.png

Comment: So what is your problem? on your fiddle you have situation as is shown on the picture.

Comment: No I don't. As you can see in the picture, I want the columns together to have 100% page width. Grey areas are columns, striped area is the actual content.

Comment: usually the only (logical) use case you'd have that is some design purpose. cant you use an background-image for the "illusion"?

Comment: It is design puropse. I can't use background image since heights of elements wiil vary depending on the content. I want to code something like this: http://fav.me/d55wnmg (note the columns on both views).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers and ideas. They were helpful and I did learn something new (my biggest 'thank you' goes to @Jon for a really great, great post). But, since I can't solve this neither with percents nor backgrounds (since my design is a little more complicated that the one provided), I made my way with jQuery. To sum up, here's my [mockup fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RayNn/1/).

Note: sometimes you'll need to change left `125` to `126`, just to make sure both ends meet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use fiddle. But this worked out fine for me.
I just used the background colors and borders to properly show the differences

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>xxx</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
        }
        #wrap {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #left {
            width: 600px;
            float: right;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
        #right {
            width: 350px;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
        #container_left {
            width: 55%;
            float: left;
            background: red;
        }
        #container_right {
            width: 45%;
            float: right;
            background: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
    <div id="container_left">
        <div id="left">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container_right">
        <aside id="right">
            <p>Sidebar</p>
        </aside>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Jan, this solution seemed right to me as well. But please note, that both `#container_left` and `_right` are 50% width, and I don't want this. Right container is smaller than the left one.

Comment: just modify the values of their respective percentages then! If you want the right container smaller, just give it a 40% and give the left container a 60%

Comment: It won't do. Proportions needs to be done in pixels, since difference in width is (roughtly) 95px. Looks like using JS is my only option.

Comment: To be more accurate, given that 600 is the 64% of 950, use that value for the left container, and 36% for the right one! Cheers!

Comment: The problem is, you can't specify the percents as accurate as pixels. But I'll have to give it another shot though.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did my calculations wrong before... I used the content proportions, and I had to use the background ones.. I downloaded your picture, and saw that the file had 1000 pixels wide. The left container was 550 (that's 55%) leaving 45% for the right container. If you use those values, no matter what size you leave the window, the content is always going to be centered... try it and let me know! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

### A Quick Note

In your comments, you are saying that you can't use a background image because the height is variable.

The way to fix this is using multiple images, and tell them to repeat or not to repeat on different parts of the page. But I'll go over this after I answer your question directly.

### Short Answer

To get 100% body width, you'll want to use percentages (`%`) on for your `width` rules. Like this:

```
#left {
  width: 60%;
}

#right {
  width: 40%;
}
```

### Fixing Some Problems

One problem you are bound to encounter when you have content that passes the bottom of the screen. In this case, you need to tell the `divs` to stay side by side.

This should do the trick:

```
#left {
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  width: 40%;
}
```

### Back to the Note

Believe me, you don't want to be using percentages on your widths. It makes sizing and scaling extremely hard to design nicely, and changes that you try to make in the future probably won't work without a complete redesign of your css.

Like I was saying before, you want to use multiple images. You'll have background image on the `body` tag that - going by the design you provided - has the *gray-to-orange* fade in it. The css would look like this:

```
body {
  background-image: url('path/to/header.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

You would then have a wrapper div like the one you already have, that holds the content and such. Inside the wrapper you have:

- A `header` (the logo and navbar), which would have no background (so you can see the `body` background).
- A `featured` section which holds that really big image in the middle. You can use negative margins to get it centered.
- A `subnav` section for those images in the middle. This would have it's own background image that has a matching part of the background of the `body` so that it appears to flow in as the image does.
- A `content` section that holds all of the content of the page. This would have an image repeating vertically to look continuous.

  ```
  #content {
    background-image: url('path/to/slice.jpg') repeat-y;
  }
  ```
- A `subfooter` section that has the curved part of the page (that *gray-to-orange* curve at the bottom).
- And finally a `footer` section that has all the stuff on the very bottom.

You can use the same structure on the inner pages, you would just use different images and spacing to change the look of the page.

### To Sum Up

You will never, **ever** need to have a `100%` width for your wrapping `div`. (I say this to generalize, there are certain styles that use this, but they aren't the same kind of design).

What you should always *try* to do first is create images for the `body`, `header`, `content`, and `footer` sections that create the look you want.

Then have your `wrap` be a set width in **pixels** that will stay in the center of the page, while the margins increase and reveal more of the background image.

Have fun and good luck with your design!